# How to shutter the "#" characters in line to one "#" char by sed?

Tags: sed

How to shutter the "#" characters to one "#" char by sed ?

From:

param=## ### ff ## e ##44

To:

param=# # ff # e #44

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do it using extended regexps:

```
vinko@parrot:~$ echo "## ### ff ## e ##44" | sed -r s/#+/#/g
# # ff # e #44
```

With regular regexps:

```
vinko@parrot:~$ echo "## ### ff ## e ##44" | sed -e s/##*/#/g
# # ff # e #44
```

Only after the equal sign:

```
vinko@parrot:~$ echo "param=## ### ff ## e ##44" | sed s/=##*/=#/g
param=# ### ff ## e ##44
```

Comment: and if I want to do it only after the "=" seperator? THX

 param=## ### ff ## e ##44 

to 

param=# ### ff ## e ##44

Answer (score 0):

posix version (for non GNU sed)

```
sed 's/#\{2,\}/#/g' YourFile
```